# How do I create a list of all of my "following" on Twitter?

Tags: twitter

I would like to monitor my Twitter account with Feedly.com. I understand I need to create a list of the people I am following in Twitter and then use a widget of the list and then create an RSS feed.

How do I add each of the people I am following quickly in one step rather than adding than one at a time?

Answer (score 2):

There is no user interface on Twitter for this.